# Pentaho dynamic Database Connection Type

Tags: dynamic, kettle

The product I've been switched to is using Pentaho to create a db for Dashboards.
It should support both Oracle and MSSQL. It uses JNDI access. Also, the same pentaho files (jobs, transformations) are used for both db types. Recently, we got a bug from production saying that the logs grow too fast on cleaning stage tables and that it actually performs delete and not truncate as it was thought till now.

I have performed a debug using pdi source code and discovered that it is caused by the fact that, because we support 2 db types, the source db connection is of type Generic. For Generic db connection `getTruncateTableStatement()` actually returns delete, instead of truncate.

My lead told me to google if there is a clean way to change this value at the runtime or at least install time. So, here I am :)

Is there a way to dynamically change this property (**Connection Type**), such that based on DatabaseType, from config file, it would be changed to a corresponding one (Oracle or MSSQL)?

P.S. We use pentaho 6.1.0.1

Comment: There is a contradiction in your request. You cannot use JNID and JDBC (=Generic DB) at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

If you use JNDI connection, the connection is defined in the file `your-data-integration-server/simple-jndi/jdbc.properties`.

Edit this file and define the database type, which is implicitly done by defining `your-connection/driver`.

Comment: It is not a problem to get the database type, but so set it dynamically to a database connection, from a transformation.

Answer (score 0):

If you use JDBC connection, there is no (simple) way of defining the database type (because the connection parameters are not the same for different database types).

What you can do is:
[image]

However, you cannot define which is the active connection in a parameter because establishing the connection will be the first thing kettle does.

Answer (score 0):

Cleaning tables should not be the responsibility of the transformations. I know it's easy, but you soon enter in errors or excessive cascade time due to deleting foreign keys.

You did not stumble on this issue yet because staging tables usually do not have foreign keys. But it is not because the problem is unseen that it does not exists.

**The clean way of cleaning staging tables is to truncate the tables before with a job level SQL-script (order of truncation matters).** Of course this step will work on Oracle as well as MSSQL, because the truncate statement is standard SQL.

If you have a lot of tables (and these tables may be identified with a naming convention), you can write a small transformation that will get the tables names, write an SQL truncate and execute the statement on table after the other. Unfortunately, you won't be able to control the order in which tables are truncated.

Comment: This is the solution I thought of, to truncate using a sql script, but I thought maybe there is a way to dynamically change connection type.

Comment: Nope. The way kettle works is to run all the steps at the same time, in different threads, and let the data flow from one to the other as soon as it is ready (Dataflow programming). Consequently, the JDBC connections are done **before** any data gets in.